# How can I solve an infix notation without converting it to any other notation?

Tags: java, data-structures

I am trying to write a program that will solve an infix notation problem without converting to any other notation.

I have three data structures(1 for operands, 1 for operators, and 1 which contains the infix notation) which can perform push,pop,enQueue,deQueue.

I also have methods for checking:

- performing the operation
- checking what the item we request is (isOperand, isOperator, isRightparenthesis, isLeftparenthesis)
- checking which checks precedence of object

How can I solve the infix notation without 1st converting to any other format?

note: parenthesis can be added, and assume notation is always proper with no errors.

I am having trouble determining the algorithm.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "solve"?  Can you give an example expected input and output to make the problem more concrete?

Comment: @wnoise I assume he means that the input represents an expression (with just numbers, no variables), and he wishes to evaluate it numerically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) useful?